# How to persist HTML(DOM) changes in a New Tab - Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a simple chrome New Tab extension where the extension takes an input from the user via a text field and then displays it.

My app.js has the following code:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        if ($('#spark').value !== null) {
            //  console.log("Hello")
            var string = $('#spark').val();
            // console.log(string);
            chrome.storage.sync.set({"myKey": string});
            $('#spark').hide();
            chrome.storage.sync.get("myKey", function(string) {
                $('#text').append(string.myKey);
            });

        }

    }
});
```

The HTML page has a div 'spark' which is the input form and a div 'text' where the text inputted in 'spark' should be displayed and is as follows:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Blank New Tab</title>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
   div {
   color: #cccccc;
   vertical-align: 50%;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 300%;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="height:40%" id='body'>
   <div id="text"> </div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <form>
     <input type="text" name="spark" id="spark">
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I run this extension, the text gets displayed for a millisecond and then rests to the original page with the input. Here's a gif of that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOciw.jpg

How do I get the text to persist on the New Tab page? Once the user types in the message and presses enter, the input form should be hidden and the page should display the text entered by the user.

Comment: chrome.storage.sync.set is asynchronous as all of chrome.* API that have a function callback parameter, so your `.get` retrieves the old value. Make sure to read [extensions overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview). Also, your form may be autosubmitted thus reloading the page. Why are you using form at all?

Comment: How else can I achieve the functionality? I want the user to input a string that persists for all New Tab pages. I have read the extensions overview but I guess I have missed something there. Let me have a look again.